# Can't import matplotlib on IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib. However, when I type import matplotlib, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

I installed matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib`.

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: what does `pip -V` return?

Comment: it returns :  pip 8.1.2 from C:\Users\ACER-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)

Comment: Is matplotlib included in the output of `pip list` ? Also a way to avoid this problem may be to switch to a python distribution to [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which generally makes installing libraries like this much easier.

Comment: Yes, matplotlib is included in the output of pip list. I probably will just anaconda then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDLE doesn't have all packages; some are more easily available (and easily installable) with Continuum's [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). You can run Python code with this, and it simplifies installing packages.